# CSS is not rendering on webpage

Tags: css

I have a webpage that uses an external CSS file for rendering my web pages on my site.  All of my pages pretty much follow the same format as far as the layout is concerned and I have different sections in the Site.css file for each page.  For some reason, one web page is not rendering the CSS correctly.  I have a div defined with an Id and it isn't recognizing the id in the div even though it is defined in the CSS file.  If I use a different id then it renders according to that Id's CSS.  Specifically, the background color is not being set.  Here is a screen shot of the site with the CSS.  As you can see from this screen shot, the `<div id="Devotions">` is not picking up the CSS.

[CSS Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbytE.png)

If I change the Id to ChristianFormaion, the page renders as I want it and the CSS is displayed as shown in the screen shot below.

[Css no Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8gVN.png)

In the View, Devotions appears in the dropdown when I set the Id for the div.  Here is the view code:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Devotions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div id="Devotions">
    <h1 class="devotions_center">DEVOTIONS</h1>
    <div class="devotions_body">
        <p><img src="~/images/Devotions_cross.jpg" alt="Assumption B.V.M." width="53" height="79" align="right" class="padding15" /></p>
        <h2><a name="CharismaticPrayerGroup" id="CharismaticPrayerGroup"></a>Charismatic Prayer Group</h2>
        <p>The Assumption Charismatic Prayer Group has been meeting every Monday evening since 1973 to offer praise, thanksgiving and petitions to our God, Father, Son and Holy Spirit. The purpose of our prayer meeting is to seek a close personal relationship with Jesus and experience the working of the Holy Spirit in our lives in a deeper way. The word “charismatic” refers to the charisms or gifts of the Holy Spirit which we prayerfully seek through praise, both verbally and in song, scripture reading, sharing of answered prayer, prophecy and petition. Some of our members have been involved for over forty years and have experienced many answers to prayer and personal transformation. We meet every Monday evening at 7:15 in the Rectory Meeting Room. If you have any questions, contact Jean Ambs at 215-355-4974.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="devotions_body">
        <h2><a name="Exposition" id="Exposition"></a>Eucharistic Adoration</h2>
        <p>Eucharistic Adoration is held every Tuesday, beginning immediately after the 8:30 a.m. Mass and concluding at 6:45 p.m. with Evening Prayer from “The Liturgy of the Hours” followed by Benediction.  Stop in for a visit any time.  Better still, consider signing up for a holy hour of personal prayer before the Blessed Sacrament.  Bring your needs to the Lord!   For more information contact Deacon Eric at 215-357-1221, ext. 24, or email deaconeric.abvm@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="devotions_body">
        <p><img src="~/images/Devotions_bible.jpg" alt="Assumption B.V.M." width="86" height="73" align="left" class="padding15" /></p>
        <h2><a name="FaithSharing" id="FaithSharing"></a>Faith Sharing</h2>
        <p>A Bible/Faith Sharing Group meets on Wednesday mornings after the 8:30 Mass in the Mary Chapel, September through May. We use the “Word Among Us” monthly publication and focus on the Scripture for the following Sunday. Come grow with us in gaining insight into readings for Mass. Everyone is invited to join our informal group. Contact Theresa Poitras at 215-357-3933 or email theresaj38@verizon.net</p>
    </div>
    <div class="devotions_body">
        <h2><img src="~/images/Devotions_rosary.jpg" alt="Assumption B.V.M." width="172" height="89" align="right" /><a name="Rosary" id="Rosary"></a>Rosary</h2>
        <p>Prayed in Church at 8:00 AM before the 8:30 AM daily Mass.</p>
        <h2><a name="PrayerPhoneTree" id="PrayerPhoneTree"></a>Prayer Line</h2>
        <p>A group of parishioners volunteer to pray for the special intentions of our parish. If you have a request that you would like prayers for, please call Ginger Henry at 215-357-3394.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="devotions_body">
        <h2><a name="Miraculous" id="Miraculous"></a>Miraculous Medal Novena</h2>
        <p>Prayed in Church Thursday mornings following the 8:30 AM Mass.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="devotions_body">
        <h2><img src="~/images/Devotions_Mary.jpg" alt="Assumption B.V.M." width="84" height="96" align="right" /><a name="LegionofMary" id="LegionofMary"></a>Legion of Mary</h2>
        <p>The Legion of Mary is a lay Catholic organization founded by the Servant of God, Frank Duff, in Dublin, Ireland on September 7, 1921. Long before the recognition that the laity is vital to the work of the Catholic Church after Vatican Council II, the Legion of Mary, as a lay apostolic association with the approval of the Catholic Church and the intercession of Mary Immaculate, seeks the holiness of its members as they actively invite other people to holiness by doing the works assigned them by their Spiritual Director. In our parish, Our Lady of the Assumption Praesidium, the basic unit of the Legion, meets on Thursdays at 6:45 p.m. in the Mary Chapel, which is to the right of the church vestibule as you enter our church.</p>

        <p>Currently, Father Mike Davis, Spiritual Director, asks the legionaries to visit homebound parishioners, residents of nursing homes and to bring the Pilgrim Virgin Statue to parishioners’ homes as requested. The primary purpose of the Pilgrim Virgin Statue home visitation is to help families to respond to the requests of the Blessed Mother Mary during the 1917 apparitions at Fatima: to return to God, make reparation for sins and to pray the Rosary for Peace. For more information, please contact Elaine Flood at 215-962-4312 or email lainey39forever@yahoo.com</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS in the Site.css file for devotions:

```
/* ========================================================================================*/
/* devotions.aspx */
#Devotions {
    background-color: #dee4fe;
    padding: 5px;
}

.devotions_body {
    padding: 5px 15px 15px 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.devotions_center {
    text-align: center;
}

.devotions_left {
    text-align: left;
}

.devotions_right {
    text-align: right;
}

.devotions_color {
    color: #005bac;
    color: #006699;
}
```

Here is the CSS for the ChristianFormation:

```
/* ========================================================================================*/
/* christianformation.aspx */
#ChristianFormation {
    background-color: #dee4fe;
    padding: 5px;
}

.christianformation {
    color: #B4C1E3;
    border-width: 0;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.christianformation_hr {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Any help in identifying why the Devotions CSS is not rendering is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From the screenshot with no issue you can see that the #ChristianFormation is actually in site.css.

Comment: Agreed that is what the problem is.  However, Devotions is also in site.css.  As noted in the post.  I'm trying to figure out why it is not being recognized when the page is rendered.